# Setting recycle properties on IIS7 App Pools using powershell 2.0

Tags: iis-7, powershell-2.0

I am trying to set the current properties using powershell

1. disallowRotationOnConfigChange
2. disallowOverlappingRotation

I do this with the following code

```
$appPools = Get-childItem IIS:\AppPools
foreach ($appPool in $appPools)
{
    $appPool.name
    Set-ItemProperty $path -Name recycling.disallowRotationOnConfigChange -value True
    Set-ItemProperty $path -Name recycling.disallowOverlappingRotation -value True
}
```

after this executes I go check in inetmgr and the properties have not budged from False... what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me this script misses an entire line :)

for those who haven't spotted it the script should read

```
$appPools = Get-childItem IIS:\AppPools
foreach ($appPool in $appPools)
{
    $path = "IIS:\AppPools\$($appPool.Name)"
    $appPool.name
    Set-ItemProperty $path -Name recycling.disallowRotationOnConfigChange -value True
    Set-ItemProperty $path -Name recycling.disallowOverlappingRotation -value True
}
```

no good not defining $path :)

This fixes the above script

Comment: Did this fix it?

Comment: @krystanhonour you can accept it now :)